# "Data type mismatch exception" in updating datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have the following code for update my database. The update works fine but when i try to  refresh the data grid view, the programs throws a "data type mismatch in criteria exception"
Here's the code

```
string gen = "";
        if (male_rdbtn.Checked)
            gen = "M";
        if (female_rdbtn.Checked)
            gen = "F";
        //Updates the database
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        da.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        da.UpdateCommand.Connection = GetConnection();
        da.UpdateCommand.CommandText =
           "UPDATE patients SET " +
           "firstlastname ='" + nametxt.Text +
           "', birthdate='" + birthtxt.Text +
           "', birthplace='" + birthcmb.SelectedItem +
           "', gender='" + gen +
           "', bloodtype='" + bloodcmb.SelectedItem +
           "', telnum='" + teltxt.Text +
           "', address='" + addresstxt.Text +
           "' WHERE patientid=" + txt;

        da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da.UpdateCommand.Connection.Close();

        //My code to refresh data grid view
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = GetConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE patientid = '"+ txt +"'";


        OleDbDataAdapter dad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        dad.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dad.Fill(ds, "patients");//mismatch exception is thrown here
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "patients";



        cmd.Connection.Close();



    }
```

How can i fix this. Thanks

EDIT: Solved by correcting syntax

Comment: Wrap your objects that implement IDisposable in using blocks. Use parametrized queries. And you will probably need to call ToString on your SelectedItems too. And in your update statement patientId needs to have single quote characters around the value.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn Thanks so much i got it now..

Comment: What happen to your code if you have a patient with a `firstlasname' = `James O'Connor`? Please, NEVER write sql commands concatenating user input directly in your sql commands. You are on the road to hell....